# How to do the Facebook authentication in a dialog instead of Safari webpage

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

When do a iPhone app that uses Facebook connect, I followed the guide for SSO (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/) but I hate that SSO sends me to a Safari Page. I want to do the authentication in a dialog instead.

Please tell me if you ever met the same issues. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Facebook.m` you need to change the following code:

```
- (void)authorize:(NSArray *)permissions
         delegate:(id<FBSessionDelegate>)delegate {

    [_permissions release];
    _permissions = [permissions retain];

    _sessionDelegate = delegate;

    /*  safariAuth should be NO  */
    [self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO];

    /*
         authorizeWithFBAppAuth: will launch the Facebook App
         safariAuth: will launch Mobile Safari

         When both of these are set to NO, the Facebook Login
         Dialog will appear inside of your app.
     */
}
```